# How to simulate Curl Send/Receive errors

Tags: curl, libcurl

I am new to `libcurl`, please help me for below queries

Simulate curl errors mentioned [here](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

> CURLE_SEND_ERROR (55)

Failed sending network data.

> CURLE_RECV_ERROR (56)

Failure with receiving network data.

Client is send the request to server using curl, if request fails with `CURLE_RECV_ERROR(56),` Client will be retry the request again with server.

Need to simulate above error. could some help me

Answer (score 1):

`LD_PRELOAD` send/recv replacements/wrappers that can return whatever return codes you want on demand!

Comment: thanks Daniel,
Could you please explain more above statement, like, how to use LD_PRELOAD for my use case my use case?  explain in-depth one use case

Comment: Nice and simple explanation: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/simple-ld-preload-tutorial/